# How to remove MenuItemTitle from TinyMCE?

Tags: javascript, tinymce, drop-down-menu

I have enabled the 'fontsizeselect' plugin in tinyMCE. My question is how do I remove the header (title) of the drop-down menu?

[image]

Edit:

I've tried removing it using JQuery .remove(), but after that the height of whole list is calculated wrong.

The second option I tried was:

http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/API3:method.tinymce.ui.DropMenu.remove

But that just went wrong and "fontsizeselect.remove(title)" (analogically to .add) makes error to whole tinyMCE - "missing : after property id". Problably it is completly bad method to do this.

The third option was editing tiny_mce\themes\advanced\editor_template_src.js line 467:

```
c = ed.controlManager.createListBox('fontsizeselect', {title : 'advanced.font_size', onselect : function(v) {...}
```

but seems, that TinyMCE developers thought, that every drop-down must have title/header

Comment: What's wrong about this? I'm not experienced SO user, so don't know what have done wrong.

Comment: Questions on StackOverflow should be about solving specific programming problems. If your question doesn't include some code, it's probably not the right place to ask. You also need to show that you've put some effort into solving the problem yourself. Explain what you've tried and why/how those solutions didn't work. Asking a question on SO should be a last resort, after exhausting all other research avenues. There are a lot of guidelines as to how you can write a great question in the FAQ and here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7931/faq-for-stack-exchange-sites

Comment: It's *better*, enough to justify me removing my downvote, but it's still not great. The phrase "something goes wrong" is useless to us. What goes wrong?

Comment: I don't think it's possible (with reasonable effort) - I peeked into the source of Tiny and it seems to be implied that *every* select box has some title. Good luck.

Comment: So there is no way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED:
before initialization of MCE we have to override the menu rendering function

```
(function(tinymce) {
var DOM = tinymce.DOM, Event = tinymce.dom.Event, each = tinymce.each, Dispatcher = tinymce.util.Dispatcher, undef;

tinymce.create('tinymce.ui.ListBoxNoTitle:tinymce.ui.ListBox', {
    renderMenu : function() {
        var t = this, m;

        m = t.settings.control_manager.createDropMenu(t.id + '_menu', {
            menu_line : 1,
            'class' : t.classPrefix + 'Menu mceNoIcons',
            max_width : 250,
            max_height : 150
        });

        m.onHideMenu.add(function() {
            t.hideMenu();
            t.focus();
        });

/*          m.add({
            title : t.settings.title,
            'class' : 'mceMenuItemTitle',
            onclick : function() {
                if (t.settings.onselect('') !== false)
                    t.select(''); // Must be runned after
            }
        });
*/
        each(t.items, function(o) {
            // No value then treat it as a title
            if (o.value === undef) {
                m.add({
                    title : o.title,
                    role : "option",
                    'class' : 'mceMenuItemTitle',
                    onclick : function() {
                        if (t.settings.onselect('') !== false)
                            t.select(''); // Must be runned after
                    }
                });
            } else {
                o.id = DOM.uniqueId();
                o.role= "option";
                o.onclick = function() {
                    if (t.settings.onselect(o.value) !== false)
                        t.select(o.value); // Must be runned after
                };

                m.add(o);
            }
        });

        t.onRenderMenu.dispatch(t, m);
        t.menu = m;
        }
    });
})(tinymce);
```

And with this comment on "m.add" You just have to add

```
tinyMCE.init({
        setup : function(ed) {
            ed.onBeforeRenderUI.add(function(ed){
        ed.controlManager.setControlType('listbox', tinymce.ui.ListBoxNoTitle);
            });
        }

});
```

this setup to standard initialization of tinyMCE. So, it can be done without editing source files.